# Post comments don't show

Tags: comments

Recently I found out the post's comments don't display in post url. for example this post
https://akhbarejadid.com/196055/ has more than 50 comments as you can see in image below
[image]

I don't know when and how this problem appeared?!! You should know I don't any changed in theme or plugins except updated some plugins like aksimet and seo yoast

Comment: It usually helps to start with some basic troubleshooting: copy everything to a staging or local site, then deactivate plugins and switch to a default theme (like Twenty Twenty-One). If everything works, switch your theme and test again, and if it still works, activate plugins one by one, testing again, until you find out which component is affecting it. It's most likely to be your theme.

Comment: yes it seems the problem is from the theme. But I am wondering everything worked fine before I updated 2-3 default plugins like aksimet

Comment: Akismet does have to do with comments, so that could also be a culprit. Usually you want to isolate which theme or plugin is causing the issue, and then if it's third-party, contact that theme or plugin's author for support. This site mostly supports custom code, not third-party themes or plugins.